# UIButton is not setting text

Tags: objective-c, arrays, for-loop, text, uibutton

I seem to have a problem in my Objective C iOS app where I am creating multiple buttons depending on the amount of objects in an array. I know Swift, so I replicated the logic into Swift, and it worked. Yet in Objective C, I am unable to see the text of the button (after I remove the for loop) or create multiple buttons. For example, I have an array full of three names. I would like to create a button for each name with the title set to the corresponding name. So far, I have this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];


NSMutableArray *ages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
    [ages addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
}


UIScrollView  *scrollView= [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
scrollView.delegate= self;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets= NO;
scrollView.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
scrollView.scrollEnabled= YES;
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
[scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];


CGFloat xValue = 0;
for(int x=0; x > ages.count; x++){
    UIButton  *button= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue ,0 , 172 ,65)];
    UIColor *buttonOutline = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    button.layer.borderColor = [buttonOutline CGColor];
    button.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0]];
    button.titleLabel.text = [ages objectAtIndex:x];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scrollView addSubview:button];
    NSLog(@"Button Added");
    xValue = button.frame.size.width + 40;

}

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xValue, 65);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

}

- (void)test:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSLog(@"Clicked %@", sender.titleLabel.text);
}



@end
```

If anyone sees anything wrong with this code, please point it out!

Thanks,

Arnav K.

Comment: [button setTitle: [ages objectAtIndex:x]];

Comment: Don't you need to add a `forControlEvents:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found four problems (there may be others) that stop this working correctly:

1) The for loop bound when setting up the ages array is incorrect.
2) The for loop bound when creating the buttons is incorrect.
3) You are setting the buttonOutline colour incorrectly.
4) xValue is being updated incorrectly.

Here is the viewDidLoad method after the changes have been made:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *ages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // UPDATED
        [ages addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
    }


    UIScrollView  *scrollView= [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    scrollView.delegate= self;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets= NO;
    scrollView.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled= YES;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];


    CGFloat xValue = 0;
    for(int x=0; x < ages.count; x++){ // UPDATED
        UIButton  *button= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue ,0 , 172 ,65)];
        UIColor *buttonOutline = [UIColor redColor]; // UPDATED
        button.layer.borderColor = [buttonOutline CGColor];
        button.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
        [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0]];
        button.titleLabel.text = [ages objectAtIndex:x];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:button];
        NSLog(@"Button Added");
        xValue += button.frame.size.width + 40; // UPDATED

    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xValue, 65);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

I have marked the four lines I changed with a UPDATED comment so you can compare them to the original.

**EDIT**
To change the text and text colour use the following:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:[ages objectAtIndex:x] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and remove this:

```
button.titleLabel.text = [ages objectAtIndex:x];
```

You need to do this because you can set different text for the different states of the button and this is all handled automatically for you.

Comment: I tried running this but the titles aren't being set. I even added a font color but the text isn't appearing. The code for the title color was `[button setTitleColor:buttonOutline forState:UIControlStateSelected];`. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry, `[button setTitleColor:buttonOutline forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Sorry, I got everything else working and forgot the original issue.  I will edit the answer.